# Recognizing sentences that don't end in two spaces

Tags: text, sentences, writing

I'm not going to weigh in on whether ending sentences with two spaces is the One True Way or an abomination. All I know is that I show no signs of establishing a consistent habit of hitting the spacebar twice at the end of a sentence. So, given that: what's an ideal set of `sentence-*` customizations that will accurately recognize most English sentence endings without the aid of two spaces?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try setting `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil`.

Comment: Well I feel stupid. I'd missed that and thought I'd need to come up with a regex.