# Any functionality differences using a two-space vs one-space convention at the end of a sentence?

Tags: sentences, typography

**Q:** What practical reasons are there *not* to set `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil`?

A recently-revived thread on [recognizing sentences that don't end in two spaces](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/475/recognizing-sentences-that-dont-end-in-two-spaces) inspired this question.

The [Emacs manual node on sentences](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sentences.html) notes that the sentence commands assume that we use the American typist's convention of putting two spaces at the end of a sentence (as opposed to, say, the French convention of one space).  Arguments for/against the two-space convention apparently gets pretty polemical (eg, [this Slate piece](http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/technology/2011/01/space_invaders.html)).

I don't particularly care about looks insofar as I let LaTeX handle my type-setting, but the two-space convention is pounded into muscle memory.  However, when I paste text into an Emacs buffer from other sources (webpages, etc.), it's almost always in the one-space convention.  That's kind of annoying in a how-dare-they-differ-from-me sort of way, and I'm tempted to set `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil` to Deal With Reality.  I never have, however, because I've always assumed that Something Will Break if I did so.  I just don't have any firm basis for that assumption.

So: are there any practical consequences in terms of loss of functionality for setting `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil`?  The only significant change I can think of is that the fill functions will change the two-space convention into the one-space convention.

Comment: Love this question, I completely understand what you feel...

Comment: Even the Slate article that you cite argues that in monospaced type a double-space convention may help to identify the ending of sentences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only consequence I'm seeing, is the ability to recognize periods from abbreviations.

As stated by [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sentences.html):

> If you want to use just one space between sentences, you can set the
>   variable `sentence-end-double-space` to nil to make the sentence
>   commands stop for single spaces. However, this has a drawback: there
>   is no way to distinguish between *periods that end sentences* and
>   *those that indicate abbreviations*.
>
> For convenient and reliable editing, we therefore recommend you follow
>   the two-space convention. The variable `sentence-end-double-space` also
>   affects
>   [filling](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fill-Commands.html#Fill-Commands).

I've never used the two-space convention, I think, it depends on how/what you are editing.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer to the question as stated ("what do I lose if I set `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil`"), but rather something like the [third way](http://www.xkcd.com/1285/);-).  (Also, it is a (partial) copy from a [post I've just written on my blog](http://mbork.pl/2014-10-28_Single_vs_double_spaces); if this is inappropriate, someone please delete this, but I hope this might be helpful.)

So, basically, why do you want to *lose* anything by setting something against your liking?  This is Emacs, after all!

```
(defvar sentence-end-double-space-threshold 2
  "How many occurrences of \".  \" per kilobyte should be enough
  to declare this file as using two spaces after sentences.")

(defun set-sentence-end-double-space ()
  "Set `sentence-end-double-space' according to how often the
  literal string \".  \" occurs in the current buffer."
  (make-local-variable 'sentence-end-double-space)
  (if (>= (* (count-matches "\\.  ") 1024)
      (* (buffer-size) sentence-end-double-space-threshold))
      (setq sentence-end-double-space t)
    (setq sentence-end-double-space nil)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'set-sentence-end-double-space)
```

Now when you open a file, Emacs decides (using the very conservative value of `sentence-end-double-space-threshold`, which you can `setq` to whatever you feel right) which style it is. (Obviously, this does not help in case of pasting from the browser or whatever. It could be done, advising `yank` and – if needed – replacing spaces in the yanked text as necessary, but hey, I only had 15 minutes for that!)

PS. Of course, it does not take into account periods at EOLs etc.; but again, the threshold is very low.