# Customize emacs Captain Mode so that a new sentence is assumed to be one space after period instead of two

Tags: sentences

I am a Linux and EMACS noob. I have installed captain mode in EMACS and love it except that it won't start capitalizing the next sentence unless there are two spaces after a period. I stopped that practice long ago and only put one space after a period. Is there a way to customize captain-mode so that it would recognize a new sentence beginning after only one space? Or is there another mode that would do this instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any functionality differences using a two-space vs one-space convention at the end of a sentence?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2766/any-functionality-differences-using-a-two-space-vs-one-space-convention-at-the-e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set variable `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil` in your init file:

```lisp
(setq-default sentence-end-double-space nil)
```

`C-h v` tells us:

> `sentence-end-double-space` is a variable defined in `paragraphs.el`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Non-`nil` means a single space does not end a sentence.
>
> This is relevant for filling.  See also `sentence-end-without-period`
> and `colon-double-space`.
>
> This value is used by the function `sentence-end` to construct the
> regexp describing the end of a sentence, when the value of the variable
> `sentence-end` is `nil`.  See Info node ‘(elisp)Standard Regexps’.

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much!